# what would be the function definitions for these 2 pieces of code

Tags: c++

I have code that I need working to make it calculate the cost/year of car as well as the cost of the car after 10%

I know I need to add function definitions in the void functions( which i do not know how to do or what to write in it.)

Also add the main function which I add some of but can't get the rest

Please help. I tried forever.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Car;

  int year;
  double cost;

void read_car_record(Car&, new_car);


void Car update_cost(car old_record);


}
 int main(){
cout << "enter the year of the car: "<<endl;
   cin<< "year";
cout << "Enter the cost of the car: "<<endl;
   cin<< "cost";
```

Comment: I have no idea what you want to do, or what is broken. Do you mean `struct Car { \*random code\* }`, instead of `struct Car; \*random code\* }`? Is this homework?

Comment: I was sick and didn't get the answer from the teacher so i'm asking here. what I am looking for is how to make my code actually work. Work I mean calculate the cost/year/cost of car after 10%. The function definitons is what I don't have and is what I need

Comment: After 10% of... what?

Comment: And why does update_cost take an old_record? FYI, C++ (and every one of the languages I know or have ever heard of) is case sensitive, so `car` and `Car` mean different things.

Comment: Oh sorry 10% discount. All of this is my teachers code so I don't know why she has what she has. She just wants me to add the function definitions and main class.

Comment: Sorry, but StackOverflow is not a _do my homework for me_ site. Please see [What topics can I ask here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: If your teacher is writing things like `void Car update_cost(car old_record)`, find a new teacher.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess at your chaos:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Car
{
  int year;
  double cost;
};

void read_car_record(Car& new_car);
void update_cost(Car& old_car);

int main()
{
    Car myCar;

    cout << "enter the year of the car: "<<endl;
    cin >> myCar.year;

    cout << "Enter the cost of the car: "<<endl;
    cin  >> myCar.cost;
}
```

Comment: Still have the painfully confusing `void Car update_cost(Car& old_car);`.

Comment: Oops... I missed that. fixed now.

Comment: apparently cout and cin are not declared in the scope according to my errors.

Comment: @user2910032: How do you know?  Do you have an error message to show us?

Comment: Yes 
structcar.cc: In function 'int main()':
structcar.cc:18:5: error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope
structcar.cc:18:44: error: 'endl' was not declared in this scope
structcar.cc:19:5: error: 'cin' was not declared in this scope

Comment: If you have information such as error messages, **Put it in your question!**  *(not in a comment below an answer)*

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want

```
struct Car{
    int year;
    double cost;
};
```

also your function signatures aren't right. update_cost returns void (nothing) or Car but not both. You have to chose one